# Access properties from UIView subclass

Tags: ios, uiview, properties, uiviewcontroller, subclass

I have a pretty cluttered display where I need a textField, 9 UIlabels and 9 UIButtons with lines connecting them in a inverted-tree shape. Everything is created on code.

In order to tiddy up my UIViewController from display code such as constraints and everything display-realted, I've created a subclass of UIView. Inside this subclass of UIView I've created all the labels and buttons as public properties.

On Storyboard I changed the class of self.view to the new subclass I created. When I run the simulator it displays correctly what I wanted.

The problem comes when I try to access the public properties of the subclass I've created, for instance when I try to change a label's text. When I type on the viewController Xcode doesn't show all the properties I've set previously.

Now I don't know if my approach is straight-on wrong or if I'm missing something. Would it be better to create a subclass of UIViewController and work on from there?

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `view` property in your interface extension:

```
#import "CustomView.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CustomView *view;

@end

@implementation ViewController

// Only needed if you're not using storyboards
-(void)loadView
{
    self.view = [CustomView new];

    // Setup the rest of your view, e.g.
    self.view.customLabel.text = @"Custom label text";
}

@end
```

EDIT: I've just noticed your using storyboards, so the `loadView` isn't needed, but I've left this in for completeness for others

Comment: Cool, I knew I was missing something. Is there any easy way to override the buttons actions?. Now I'm setting the target of each individual button on viewDidLoad. I wonder if there is a easier way...

Comment: @Marcal Yep, in storyboard drag the "Touch up inside" outlet to your view controller file.

Comment: @Marcal have a look at [this](http://rshankar.com/different-ways-to-connect-ibaction-to-uibutton/), hopefully this will explain it - it is for nibs and not storyboards, but its the same idea :)

Comment: yes, thanks. I know all this, but I'm doing all the self.view subViews by code, so I cannot drag anything on storyboard. It's now all set. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast it to your view.like this

```
MyViewClass *MyView=(MyViewClass*)self.view;


if ([self.view isKindOfClass:[MyViewClass class]]) {

    //do something like MyView.urProperty 

    // Don't forget to import the MyViewClass.h in the class        

}
```